# rstudio: turn off notification that new breakpoints will be activated when file sourced

Tags: rstudio

This is pretty whiny, I know, but I find it distracting when I insert a breakpoint during a debugging session and RStudio pops up that notice about the breakpoint not being activated until file re-sourced. Is there a way to turn this notification off? The hollow red dot is clear enough for me!

Comment: One for official RStudio support channels I think...

Comment: Okay. I'll check there. Wondering if I should delete this SO post? Happy to update here, tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Official word is "can't do it."](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115008047073-turn-off-notification-that-new-breakpoints-will-be-activated-when-file-sourced)

[Feature request submitted](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1939).